# Wrapping passwords in passwords many times is a strong security method?

Tags: security

Say you have an encrypted zip file in an encrypted zip file n times would the increase of n also increase the level of security for the main contains?

Comment: What do you mean by "a 30sec layer?" When you say "as many passwords that can be generated," by what mechanism are you generating those passwords? What do you mean by "with great passwords?" Are these all unique, random passwords that are only known by a human (or stored outside the system)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: By "a 30sec layer" I mean in a scenario where layers are created for 30 seconds, where the password is generated (ex. random characters). This isn't for human use, just a thought I had. I meant for this question to be a bit abstract as instead of your typically password you could use something else like some encryption.

Comment: The tool you want to explore is called a PBKDF; the most famous is called PBKDF2. Their intent is to "burn time" when converting human-generated passwords into proper cryptographic keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of open questions about what you mean (see comments), but in principle, the answer is straightforward.

Encrypting with password A and password B is (for properly designed crypto systems) security-wise identical to, or at least no better than, encrypting once with A+B. You have simply increased the size of your keyspace (at least up to the size of the underlying cryptosystem's keyspace). That's a good thing, but if your user can memorize two 8 character passwords, it's just as effective to have them memorize one 16 character password (or type the two 8 character passwords one after another). For well designed systems, the 16 character password will be dramatically faster to decrypt than the two 8 character passwords (running the KDF one time is much faster than twice). If you wanted it to take longer (to slow down attackers), then you should increase the number of iterations in your KDF, not create two layers.

But as a rule, you should avoid double-encrypting. Most encryption schemes are not nearly as well studied for this use case, and some encryption schemes can become weaker when applied multiple times, particularly using non-random passwords.

(I've used a lot of technical terms here that may not be obvious if you don't have a crypto background. If anything is unclear, comment and I'll expand.)